# Get blob of uploaded file by filepond

Tags: reactjs, filepond

I'm using filepond to upload a file to server in react-js. everything works fine and I can upload the file successfully.
but i need to keep the uploaded file in browser (or maybe the path of local file) so i can show it to user at next page. it seems that browsers do not show the absolute path of selected file (for security reasons). I wonder it is possible the blob of selected file. is there any solution?
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [URL.createObjectURL()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL) to create a URL from your Blob or File. This url can be passed to the next screen.

```
const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
```

Depending on the type of file your can use the object url to display the file directly e.g. in an img-tag or you can convert it back into a blob.

```
<img src={url} />
```

or

```
const blob = await fetch(url).then(r => r.blob());
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, but i can't get the blob from filepond. how can I get it from input?

Comment: I guess you can retrieve it from filepond using `getFiles()` https://pqina.nl/filepond/docs/api/instance/methods/#getting-files or subscribing to the `FilePond:addfile` event https://pqina.nl/filepond/docs/api/instance/events/

Comment: getFiles() return only name of files, but i'll try to use addfile event... thanks

Comment: Are you sure? The docs state that at least getFile() will return a `FileItem` https://pqina.nl/filepond/docs/api/file-item

Comment: i'll check it again, but last time i tried it i could only get file name.

Comment: thanks for your comments. i could get the file by getFile(0) function and then convert it to base 64 by getFileEncodeDataURL function and then change it to a blob by using fetch(url). now i'm trying to pass it to next page . thank you very much